# Extracting MSDeploy Zip package using variables

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I’m setting up an automated build in VSTS that will FTP the published files to my server.

I have this working but the way I’ve achieved it, I feel is hacky and non-sustainable.

the process as you can see from the screenshots will publish the artefact which consists of a readme, cmd file and a zip containing all my publish files and then I extract the ZIP with the very explicit location below.

> $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\temp\Content\d_C\a\1\s\IntermittentBug\IntermittentBug\obj\Release_EukHosts\Package\PackageTmp

I’m using a hosted build server in VSTS but as the path contains

> d_C\a\1\s\

I assume this will change in time. What I need is a variable to cater for this path so it will always succeed.

How can I update this to make it more efficient and sustainable?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

First, as jessehouwing said that the variable is called `Build.SourcesDirectory`.

Regarding the path structure, the simple way is specifying `/p:PackageTempRootDir=""` msbuild argument in **Visual Studio Build** task to remove the source path structure, then the path will be like `Content\D_C\PackageTmp`.

On the other hand, you also can publish the web app through **File System** mode.

Answer (score 2):

This variable is caught in a predefined variable called `Build.SourcesDirectory`. see the [complete list of predefined variables here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops).

In your batch or powershell scripts this variable is available as a environment variable called `%BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY%` / `$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY`.

Comment: link has gone bad

Comment: fixed the link.